# Como corro o Ooo4Kids no Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

O Ooo4Kids deixou de ser desenvolvido e ao tentar correr no Ubuntu (a partir do 15.04) obtenho o seguinte erro:

> /usr/lib/ooo4kids-1.3/program/soffice.bin: /usr/lib/ooo4kids-1.3/program/> ../basis-link/ure-link/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not 
>   found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)

Obrigado,

Comment: Muchas gracias, no hay problema con este solucion ! merci beaucoup ! thanks a lot, it did it !

Answer (score 2):

Esse problema ocorre porque o Ooo4Kids usa um libstdc++.so.6 próprio em vez de usar o do sistema, que seria o mais apropriado.

A forma mais simples de resolver o problema é apagar (ou mover) o libstdc++.so.6 do Ooo4Kids:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/ooo4kids-1.3/basis-link/ure-link/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/ooo4kids-1.3/basis-link/ure-link/lib/libstdc++.so.6.old
```

e criar um link para o libstdc++.so.6 do sistema:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/ooo4kids-1.3/basis-link/ure-link/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

Isso deverá resolver o problema.